# error while installing heroku through snap

Tags: linux, fedora, sudo, heroku-cli

while I am installing heroku on fedora it shows an errod

```
bash-5.0$ sudo snap install heroku --classic
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "core" (8935) from channel "stable" (unexpected EOF)
```

how to solve it

Comment: Please edit your question to show Fedora version, like Fedora 31 - x86_64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found answer.
I used standalone installation for installing heroku

```
$ curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

The above problem may due to the bad internet connection. And I realized that snap is not really a good tool. And it has some issues.